# Swift prevent Optional("") or nil in string concatenate result | Create query string from object

Tags: ios, swift, string, concatenation

I have struct like this:

```
struct Request {
    var page: Int
    var name: String?
    var favoriteName: String?
    var favoriteId: Int? 
}
```

---

Then I convert it to Dictionary

```
func toDict() -> [String:Any] {
    var dict = [String:Any]()
    let otherSelf = Mirror(reflecting: self)
    for child in otherSelf.children {
        if let key = child.label {
            dict[key] = child.value
        }
    }
    return dict
}
```

---

If I loop it to modify and concatenate using those Dict key & value *to create query string*:

```
var queryString: String {
    var output: String = ""
    for (key,value) in toDict() {
        output +=  "\(key)" + "=\(value)&"
    }
    output = String(output.dropLast())
    return output
}
```

---

Does anyone know how to prevent nil, Optional(""), Optional(25) string added in the concatenation process ?

---

> current result: page=20&name=nil&favoriteName=Optional("")&favoriteId=Optional(25)
> expected result: page=20&name=&favoriteName=&favoriteId=25

Edit: Thank you everyone , wasn't really expecting so much answer tho. Let me edit the title to help future developers search.

Comment: Using `Mirror` outside debugging is almost always a bad idea. Also note that when encoding to URL, the order of query parameters can be important and also a parameter can appear multiple times, e.g. `param=a&param=b`. Also note that both keys and values should be URL-encoded before concatenation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to use the `URLComponents` and `URLQueryItem` structs.

This is my approach to solving your problem.

First I added an enum to avoid having hardcoded strings.

```
struct Request {
    var page: Int
    var name: String?
    var favoriteName: String?
    var favoriteId: Int?
}

enum RequestValues: String {
    case page
    case name
    case favoriteName
    case favoriteId
}
```

Then I made this helper function to return the non nil `vars` from the `Request` instance as an array of `URLQueryItem`.

```
func createQuery(request: Request) -> [URLQueryItem] {
    
    var queryItems: [URLQueryItem] = []
    
    queryItems.append(URLQueryItem(name: RequestValues.page.rawValue, value: "\(request.page)"))
    
    if let name = request.name {
        queryItems.append(URLQueryItem(name: RequestValues.name.rawValue, value: name))
    }
    
    if let favoriteName = request.favoriteName {
        queryItems.append(URLQueryItem(name: RequestValues.favoriteName.rawValue, value: favoriteName))
    }
    
    if let favoriteId = request.favoriteId {
        queryItems.append(URLQueryItem(name: RequestValues.favoriteId.rawValue, value: "\(favoriteId)"))
    }
    
    return queryItems
}
```

Then you can get the query string like this:

```
let queryString = queryItems.compactMap({ element -> String in
    guard let value = element.value else {
        return ""
    }
    let queryElement = "\(element.name)=\(value)"
    return queryElement
})
```

this will give you the expected result in your question.

> page=20&name=&favoriteName=&favoriteId=25

But you should use the `URLComponents` struct to build your url as such.

```
func buildURL() -> URL? {
    
    var urlComponents = URLComponents()
    urlComponents.scheme = "https"
    urlComponents.host = "google.com"
    urlComponents.queryItems = queryItems
    urlComponents.path = "/api/example"
    urlComponents.url

    guard let url = urlComponents.url else {
        print("Could not build url")
        return nil
    }
    
    return url
}
```

This would will give you the url with the query.
It would look like this :

https://google.com/api/example?page=5&name=nil&favoriteName=Hello&favoriteId=9

Comment: I will upvote because this is a far better solution that using `Mirror` and it actually handles URL-encoding. However, be careful with `URLQueryItem`. Sometimes it doesn't encode properly. Personally, I had a problem with the `+` sign which was not encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Check if value is nil before insert it in the output, if the value is nil you can provide a default value:

```
var queryString: String {
    var output: String = ""
    for (key,value) in toDict() {
        output += "\(key)"

        if let value = value{
            output += "=\(value)&"
        }else{
            output += "=DefaultValue&" // Replace DefaultValue with what is good for you
        }
    }
    output = String(output.dropLast())
    return output
}
```

This is more concise:

```
var queryString: String {
    var output: String = ""
    for (key,value) in toDict() {
        output += "\(key)" + "=\(value ?? "DefaultValue")&"
    }
    output = String(output.dropLast())
    return output
}
```

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i have updated my answer, i have tested it, now it works (the response was updated some time ago)

Comment: do you know that `value ?? "DefaultValue"` would do exactly the same?

Comment: @Sulthan yes it' s equivalent, I have added it to my answer

Comment: Nitpicking, but a simpler way to writing this would be `toDict().map { (key, value) in "\(key)=\(value ?? "DefaultValue")" }.joined(separator: "&")`. Of course, both `key` and `value` should be url-encoded first.

Answer (score 0):

In model have optioanl var.
First, make your dictionary value optional

```
func toDict() -> [String: Any?] {
```

and then use the default value

```
var queryString: String {
    var output: String = ""
    for (key,value) in toDict() {
        output +=  "\(key)" + "=\(value ?? "")&" // <== Here
    }
    output = String(output.dropLast())
    return output
}
```

You can also prevent nil value in string

```
var queryString: String {
    var output: String = ""
    for (key,value) in toDict() where value != nil { //< Here
        output +=  "\(key)" + "=\(value ?? "")&" //< Here
    }
    output = String(output.dropLast())
    return output
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually creating your string you should use `URLComponents` to generate your URL and use `URLQueryItems` for your parameters. I would make your structure conform to `Encodable` and encode `NSNull` in case the value is nil. Then you just need to pass an empty string to your query item when its value is `NSNull`:

---

This will force encoding nil values:

```
extension Request: Codable {
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(page, forKey: .page)
        try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
        try container.encode(favoriteName, forKey: .favoriteName)
        try container.encode(favoriteId, forKey: .favoriteId)
    }
}
```

---

```
let request = Request(page: 20, name: nil, favoriteName: nil, favoriteId: 25)
do {
    let dictiony = (try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSONEncoder().encode(request))) as? [String: Any] ?? [:]
    let queryItems: [URLQueryItem] = dictiony.reduce(into: []) {
        $0.append(.init(name: $1.key, value: $1.value is NSNull ? "" : String(describing: $1.value)))
    }
    print(queryItems)
    var components = URLComponents()
    components.scheme = "https"
    components.host = "www.google.com"
    components.path = "/search"
    components.queryItems = queryItems
    if let url = components.url {
        print(url)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

---

This will print

> [name=, favoriteName=, page=20, favoriteId=25]
> https://www.google.com/search?favoriteName=&name=&page=20&favoriteId=25